# MAC OSX geth console error

Tags: go-ethereum, console

I have installed Geth on my mac Mojave 10.14.3 by

```
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
```

and

```
brew install ethereum
```

Just the same as the instruction and
everything goes well, but when I run

```
geth console
```

there comes a fatal error:

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: database version is v7, Geth 1.8.27-stable only supports v3
```

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: It seems you have run a version 1.9.xx from master previously, and now you are trying to run a version 1.8.xx https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19693. Either wait for 1.9.0 to reach brew or if you want to use 1.8.xx start to synch from scratch.